# Javascript Hover over visible part of PNG image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

Is there a way for me to check if the mouse is over a visible part of a PNG image?

[image: img1]

Each section is it's own image with a transparent background like:

[image: img2]

So basically I want the opacity of each region to be 1 when it is hovered, and the opacity to be 0.5 when not hovering over it. Therefore the user can see which region is being hovered over.

Is there something like onmouseover if mouse position on image != transparent then...

Comment: There's no way to do this with a plain PNG - the hover event is fired on the image as a whole, not it's opaque areas. Using SVG would be best suited to what you require. You could also use an image map, but that's very outdated.

Comment: Try image map!  www.image-maps.com/ Take a look at www.galerijaziema.lv/ziema.php

Comment: Hey Rory! If i have SVG versions of the images, how would I get it to work? I can convert them all the SVG in Illustrator

Comment: It might be better to ask how to do this with SVGs as a separate question (assuming it hasn't been asked before) since you already have answers here on how to do this with PNGs and that was the original question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_area.asp

You can take image and you will get cords for each poly by using some image tool like photoshop etc and you can handle each hover event for specific region in area tag for Image.

Simply its easy to use and to make clickable map.

Comment: I used Kirstine's www.image-maps.com link to get all the coordinates then used your map area tag to map out a region! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Take specific image in two copy.one before href link and next next href link images..


<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function()
      {
   $(".button").hover(function() 
      {
    $(this).attr("src","button-hover.png");
      }, 
  function() 
     {
    $(this).attr("src","button.png");
     }
   );
  }   
  );
 </script>

 <body>
 <img src="button.png" alt="My button" class="button" />
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: won't the .hover fire when the mouse enters the transparent areas?

Answer (score 0):

It is programmable in HTML5, without any tools or manually build the <map> <area shape=poly coords="325,25,262,....>

1. Load your layers into many hidden canvas.
2. monitor the mouse cursor relative position of the base image.
3. check if the same pixel by position offset is white or not white on each canvas.
4. toggle opacity accordingly

challenges

- performance
- also support touch and hover-less devices

Comment: This seems like an interesting way. Could you post some code to get me started?